# What is known about the Tings in 10th century Norway?

Tags: middle-ages, political-history, norway, 10th-century

There is quite a lot known about the Icelandic assemblies, but what about the Norwegian ones?

Were Gulating, Borgarting, Eidsivating and Frostating also held in summer?

Can we assume, that the procedure there was similar to the Icelandic Althing?

Did they also have a lawspeaker (how was he chosen), or did the attending chieftains (or all the attending free farmers) function as a jury?

What was the role of all the attending free people?

Were there other assemblies, which were held ad hoc or did every case have to wait for those big regional assemblies (or did they resolve some cases if possible within the local community and if, was in that case the chieftain of the affected settlement the judge)? What if a legal decision was very urgent, but couldn't be resolved in a small assembly? What if, the prosecutor belonged to a different region and therefore different assemblies, than the defendant?

Sorry for all these questions. Most of them probably won't have any concrete answers, but every information on the topic is welcome. But please don't just send links to Wikipedia, because the information there is insufficient for me and doesn't answer any of my questions.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thing_(assembly)

Comment: Thank you, but the information there is mostly about the time of the 11th and 12th century. Also the descriptions are not very detailled. Well, probably because there is not much known.

Comment: @Theword, please update the question with the information in the comment - all the information should be in the question, and all question should presumptively address why relevant Wikipedia information is insufficient.  Thanks

Comment: You would probably do well to browse through the [_Scandinavian Journal of History_](https://www.tandfonline.com/loi/shis20).

Comment: @shoover Wow, what a great source. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Theword I found that by searching Academic Source Complete for _Gulating_. You may need access to an academic library in order to read the full-text, but at least you can search through the titles and abstracts to find articles that may have what you need.

Comment: @shoover I found a full version for free of one very promising article there on another site. So that helped me a lot. Thank you.